# How can I check if a width and height value fits between a max width and height?

Tags: php, jquery, math

I have two input fields where users can enter a width and a height for a product. This product has a max height and width, for example:

```
Max width: 148
Max height: 500
```

I show a message when the user enters a value that exceeds the max width or height. The problem is at the moment I check like this:

```
if
(
$('.hoogtebreedte').eq(0).val() <= <?php echo $explodemax[0]; ?>
&& $('.hoogtebreedte').eq(1).val() <= <?php echo $explodemax[1]; ?>
)
```

Where `$explodemax[0]` contains the lowest number of the max size and `$explodemax[0]` contains the heighest number. `hoogtebreedte` are my input fields.

The message doesn't up when I enter 148 and 500 in my input fields in that order. But it should also be possible to enter that size the other way around, 500 and 148 but when I enter it like that the message does show up, meaning the user input exceeds the max height and width.

How can I fix that?

I want the message only to show up when the highest max size is exceeded, in this case 500. So 400 by 148 should be possible, 500 by 148, 148 by 300, but not 150 by 500 or 148 by 501.

I tried only checking on the heighest number but this also makes for example 500 by 500 possible, which shouldn't be possible.

Comment: Just expand the condition: `if (first field <= 148 and second <= 500) or (first field <= 500 and second <= 148)`.

Comment: @El_Vanja Great thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$('.hoogtebreedte').eq(0).val() > <?php echo $explodemax[0]; ?>
&& $('.hoogtebreedte').eq(1).val() > <?php echo $explodemax[1]; ?>
```

Instead of

```
$('.hoogtebreedte').eq(0).val() <= <?php echo $explodemax[0]; ?>
&& $('.hoogtebreedte').eq(1).val() <= <?php echo $explodemax[1]; ?>
```

Comment: OP's condition is checking for valid values (`if (within boundaries) { do something } else { show error message }`). Your suggestion inverts the branches (`if (out of boundaries) { show error message } else { do something }` and is also wrong, because it would only detect cases where **both** dimensions exceed the max (not only one of them) and also covers just one case (148 x 500), but not the other (500 x 148).